# How to use vue router in bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vue-router

i want to use the navbar dropdown menu with router link.help plz

```
<li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" to="/hiretutor">Hire Tutor</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Registration
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="/teacher">For Teacher</router-link>
          <router-link class="dropdown-item" to="student">For Student</router-link>
        </div>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link class="nav-link" to="login">Login</router-link>
        </li>
```

Comment: You need provide more detail. What do you expect to happen but isn't?